# xpath expression to select the same parent node more times

Tags: xpath, xpath-1.0

I have some HTML something like this:

```
<tr class="odd">
  <td class="player large-link">
    <a name="some name"/> <!-- I want to return this but two times. -->
  </td>
  <td class="bookings">
    <span/>
    <span/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Is possible to return `<a name="some name"/>` element two times based on the two `<span/>`?
 and sorry about my english.

Answer (score 1):

That is impossible in XPath 1, but in XPath 2 you can use for..in..return:

```
for $s in tr/td[@class="bookings"]/span return $s/../preceding-sibling::td/a
```

(assuming the html parser has inserted closing td, span tags, so the td becomes a preceding element, not a parent)

Answer (score 1):

XPath 1.0 uses the concept of node sets, whereas XPath 2.0 uses sequences. Node sets are true sets, so you cant have the same node being a member of a node-set twice. You can however do the next best thing, which is to iterate of the set of identified `span` nodes and in your higher level language, and then perform some action for each span node on the `a` node.

### Example

For example, suppose you are using XPath within XSLT. Then this fragment of an XSLT 1.0 style-sheet will perform some action on the `a` node as many times as you have `span` nodes. This fragment assumes that on entry, the focus node is the parent of the `tr` node.

```
<xsl:for-each select="tr/td[@class="bookings"]/span">
  <xsl:for-each select="(../../td[@class='player large-link']/a[name='@some name'])[1]">
    <!-- The `a` node is now the focus node. -->
    <!-- Insert desired action here on the focus node. -->
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is possible to return `<a name="some name"/>` element two times based
>   on the two `<span/>`?

Not with a single XPath 1.0 expression -- The nodes selected by an XPath 1.0 expression form a so called "node-set" -- and this is a true set -- it is deduplicated.

In Xpath 2.0 one can construct a *sequence* of nodes and a sequence can contain the same node more than once:

```
/*/*/a[@name='some name']/*[1]/.., /*/*/a[@name='some name']/*[2]/..
```

The above XPath 2.0 expression specifies a sequence containing the two wanted, identical elements.